# Copy and Paste google sheets to another google sheets when specific tab is edited

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use an onEdit trigger when a specific tab in a sheet is edited and copy it over to a specific tab in another sheet. For example: If there is any change in Sheet 1 Test 1 tab then it will copy whatever is in Sheet 1 Test 1 tab onto Sheet 2 Test 1. But if the change is in Sheet 1 Test 2 tab then it will copy whatever is in Sheet 1 Test 2 tab onto Sheet 2 Tab 2 tab.

I am able to do it for manual copy and pasting only(i can successfully copy Sheet 1 Test 1 tab to Sheet 2 Test 1 tab or Sheet 1 Test 2 tab to Sheet 2 Test 2 tab) but when I add the onEdit trigger and if loops on my code(for specifying where the edit happened and where the source and destination tabs will be) then the code doesn't run.

Here are my 2 codes(1st will be the if else loop to specify source and destination and 2nd will be the onEdit trigger):

Code 1

```
function test1()
{var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()
  if(sheet == 'Test 1') {
    //your script
  
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1xk1ayrBYXCDdHcIwi7Hukq1xnNjqSTsQ7CHQbzfFiRM'); //replace with source ID
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Test 1');
  var sr = ss.getRange("A1:N25");
  var data = sr.getValues();
  
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ut-eyO3FMBApQd62ewtINmIQSQJSDL7DCU5bRIzdBVY'); //replace with destination ID
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Test 1');
  var tr = ts.getRange("A1:N25");
  
  tr.setValues(data);
  }
  else if(sheet == 'Test 2') {
    //your script
  
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1xk1ayrBYXCDdHcIwi7Hukq1xnNjqSTsQ7CHQbzfFiRM'); //replace with source ID
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Test 2');
  var sr = ss.getRange("A1:N25");
  var data = sr.getValues();
  
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ut-eyO3FMBApQd62ewtINmIQSQJSDL7DCU5bRIzdBVY'); //replace with destination ID
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Test 2');
  var tr = ts.getRange("A1:N25");
  
  tr.setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Code 2

```
function createEditTrigger() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("test 1")
   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}
```

Here are my sample sheets:

Sample Sheet 1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xk1ayrBYXCDdHcIwi7Hukq1xnNjqSTsQ7CHQbzfFiRM/edit#gid=0

Sample Sheet 2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ut-eyO3FMBApQd62ewtINmIQSQJSDL7DCU5bRIzdBVY/edit#gid=921178690

What would be the best way to approach this if I only need to copy changes in sheet 1 into sheet 2? I dont need to monitor if any changes happens in sheet 2 nor do I need to copy anything from sheet 2 to sheet 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpreadsheetApp.openById() require authorization and onEdit() cannot perform operations that require permission.  You must use an installable trigger.